# Deriving confidence intervals for a random variable that is not observed directly (example)

Tags: probability, random-variables, standard-deviation, means

So I have a question about combining random variables. While it is given that a bottle filling machine fills with $\sigma=5$, the observed variable here is the weight of $n$ bottles, where the bottle itself has a normal distribution also.

Essentially I need to find the missing $\mu$ for the amount of wine in a filled bottle, but my intuition says that as I am observing a different variable (the weight) that itself has a distribution, I must also find a new $\sigma$.

The question is below:

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROOz4.png)

My approach so far:

Let random variables $L$, $B$ and $W$ represent the liquid amount, bottle weight and total weight respectively.

$L \sim N(\mu,25)$

$B \sim N(250,225)$

$W=L+B$

$Var(W)=Var(L)+2Cov(L,B)+Var(B)=Var(L)+Var(B)=250$

$W \sim N(998,250)$ where $998$ comes from observation of 16 samples.

Now what? I think it would be wrong to calculate the confidence interval by using $\mu =998-250$ and use $\sigma^2=25$ as this would not use the results derived above. The error in bottle weighs would not be accounted for.

Is it correct to use the standard deviation of $W$ as this also accounts for the uncertainty in the observed weight?

Comment: The first few steps are correct. However, $W \sim N(\mu + 250, 250)$ in your model instead. The sentence beginning with "For a sample of ...." means that is your observed value, the realizations of $W$. So now you construct a similar pivot for the confidence interval of mean of $W$ (with known variance it is just has a normal distribution) from the sample and do some similar algebra will get you to the confidence interval of $\mu$.

Comment: Right. I think I understand, but to confirm.

Construct a confidence interval for the observed $W$

$1.96-(\sqrt250/\sqrt16)<(\bar W - (\mu+250))<1.96+(\sqrt250/\sqrt16) $


$1.96(\sqrt250/\sqrt16)<(998 - (\mu+250))<1.96(\sqrt250/\sqrt16) $


Now rearrange for $\mu$:

$740.25< \mu <755.75$

Comment: It looks right to me.